# How can the UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE value on the server be different from the value typed in php.ini?

Tags: php, ini, upload-max-filesize

I'm facing a problem with a php.ini file on my Debian server:

- I have changed UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE and MAX_INPUT_VARS in the php.ini
  file to use Moodle properly
- I have changed all the occurrences of upload_max_filesize in all the .ini files and .conf files where I found this variable
- but when I look at the info displayed via info.php, the value for these two vars are the default ones, and not the values I typed, though php_ini_loaded_file returns the path of the file I have modified

Has someone an idea of what the problem is?

Comment: Can you share more information about your Enviroment. Docker, XAMPP etc. You have localy PHP installed?

Comment: Server software was restarted after changing?

Comment: When the global configuration does not permit these overrides, you're out of luck.

Comment: sorry for having been so long to answer. We are using apache2 pkg on debian server (hosted by OVH on a VPS plan), and PHP7.3 debian pkg. what is really amazing is I got the good values for a while, and suddenly (but the problem is that I don't really know when and after which event, they changed)

Comment: @MartinZeitler the global configuration is managed by my ourselves, for we are on a vps plan by OVH. But I must say : my domain name is managed by hostinger, and I have redirected the subdomain to the debian server (on OVH). But as I said above, it worked for a pretty long time.

Comment: I also tried to display phpinfo using the direct server IP, bypassing the DNS and the redirection, to change the values in .htaccess file in the root directory.

Comment: @user3783243 : of course, I restart the service each time I modify a conf or ini file. I even reboot the server sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

we finally have solved our problem : we created in the cond.d directory (/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d) a new ini file (30-custom-php.ini) and added the two following lines :

```
max_input_vars = 5000
upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

Hope this will help other people facing the same problem.

Jean-Paul